# d3.js sort descending positive to negative

Tags: sorting, d3.js

Would like to sort from largest positive to largest negative.

Desired output: (3,2,1,0,-1,-2,-3), Current output: (3,2,1,0,-3,-2,-1)

Initial array:

```
["-0.87", "0.51", "3.34", "1.58", "2.67", "0.51", "-1.58", "1.91", "-0.86", "-0.42", "0.23", "1.5", "-1.67", "1.9", "-2.88", "-0.63", "1.13", "-1.37", "-0.42", "-0.35", "-0.38", "0.65", "-0.41", "0.49", "1", "-0.14", "-0.07", "2.41", "3.09", "0.85", "0.51", "-0.67", "0.53", "0.98", "-0.88", "0.18", "-0.75", "-0.22", "-0.27", "-2.09", "0.01", "1.14", "-0.64", "-0.53", "3.01", "1.49", "1.56", "0", "0.67", "0.28", "-0.21", "-0.49", "-0.66", "-1.29", "0.67", "-0.76", "0.23"]
```

Sorting code:

```
dataPct.sort(d3.descending);
```

arranges like:

```
["3.34", "3.09", "3.01", "2.67", "2.41", "1.91", "1.9", "1.58", "1.56", "1.5", "1.49", "1.14", "1.13", "1", "0.98", "0.85", "0.67", "0.67", "0.65", "0.53", "0.51", "0.51", "0.51", "0.49", "0.28", "0.23", "0.23", "0.18", "0.01", "0", "-2.88", "-2.09", "-1.67", "-1.58", "-1.37", "-1.29", "-0.88", "-0.87", "-0.86", "-0.76", "-0.75", "-0.67", "-0.66", "-0.64", "-0.63", "-0.53", "-0.49", "-0.42", "-0.42", "-0.41", "-0.38", "-0.35", "-0.27", "-0.22", "-0.21", "-0.14", "-0.07"]
```

Image:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to sort strings and that's why you're getting unexpected results.  You can see that you have an array of strings as they're in quotes.

To fix this you simply need to convert the string to a number which you can do with this snippet:

```
dataPct.forEach(function (d,i) {
  dataPct[i] = +d;
});
```

There is some discussion about converting strings to number in the api documentation such as [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#wiki-parseRows).